# How to move background screen in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a game in Libgdx, in which I want to fall a ball from up word to down word and move background towards up word and update camera according to it. My code is given below...

```
    public WorldRenderer(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, World world){
  this.world = world;
  this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(FRUSTUM_WIDTH, FRUSTUM_HEIGHT);
  this.camera.position.set(FRUSTUM_WIDTH/2, FRUSTUM_HEIGHT/2, 0);
  this.spriteBatch = spriteBatch;
  positionBGY1 = 0;
  positionBGY2 = 0;

 }
 public void render(World world, float deltaTime){
  if(world.ball.position.y > - camera.position.y){
    camera.position.y = world.ball.position.y;

  }

  if(camera.position.y<0)
   camera.position.y=world.ball.position.y;

  camera.update();
  spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  renderBackground();
  renderObjects(world, deltaTime);
 }


 private void calculateBGPosition(){
  positionBGY2 = positionBGY1 + (int)FRUSTUM_HEIGHT;
  if(camera.position.y >= positionBGY2){
   positionBGY1 = positionBGY2;
  }
 }
 private void renderBackground() {
  spriteBatch.disableBlending();
  spriteBatch.begin();
  spriteBatch.draw(Assets.gamebackgroundRegion, camera.position.x - FRUSTUM_WIDTH / 2, positionBGY1 - FRUSTUM_HEIGHT / 2, FRUSTUM_WIDTH, 1.5f * FRUSTUM_HEIGHT);
  spriteBatch.draw(Assets.gamebackgroundRegion2, camera.position.x - FRUSTUM_WIDTH / 2, positionBGY2 - FRUSTUM_HEIGHT / 2, FRUSTUM_WIDTH, 1.5f * FRUSTUM_HEIGHT);
  calculateBGPosition();
  spriteBatch.end();
  }
```

Problem with my code is background screen is not moving and camera is not updated with ball movement and ball fall down out of screen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing you need to do is change one of the bg variables, so in render somehwere do something like:

```
float speed = 1;
positionBGY1+=deltaTime*speed;
positionBGY2+=deltaTime*speed;
```

As far as the camera moving with the ball I would just do this:

```
camera.position.y = Math.min(ball.y,0);
```

And I would in turn omit all of this:

```
if(world.ball.position.y > - camera.position.y){
    camera.position.y = world.ball.position.y;
}

if(camera.position.y<0)
    camera.position.y=world.ball.position.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve this is using ParrallaxLayer and ParrallaxBackground classes

it optimised the background operation so that u dont have to worry about the performance